# No script tag Detect Bot Traffic

Tags: javascript, html, bots, noscript

I hope this question doesn't get closed. I am having a real issue with real traffic where bots or automatic browsers are hitting my site.

Is there any one who tried checking " no script" tag in detail. Will this "no script" tag can execute or pull a link that I have specified through a link element or an img src element if javascript is disabled.

Problem that I have here is this... I have visitors to my website and I am trying to track users which comes with browser but with javascript not enabled.

I added iframe, img, link tags inside "no script" tag to track users without javascript so that it will add a log for me when no-js users visit the page. But looks like "no script" doesn't get executed.

I can only add iframe or js elements and I can't add server side scripts to track these users.

I have tried adding no script tag in body element with a tag like this.

```
<noscript><img src=example.com/log></noscript> 

<noscript><link src=example.com/log></noscript> 

<noscript><iframe src=example.com/log></noscript>
```

This gets triggered when I run this from Mozilla with js disabled. But when real traffic is hitting my site, this no script tag doesn't get executed. basically I am trying to figure out the visitors who is coming with a browser enabled but somehow the no script tag is not getting executed.

Installing something server side is something that I can't do. I need to have some script like js script similar to google analytics to track this. I was thinking, if I add a log in no script tag that will get executed when no js users hit my site.

google analystics also recommends adding an img src for "non js" users in no-script tag. But when I tested with real traffic to my site, these users are not getting tracked.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks Lynn

Comment: Bots do not typically process pages the same way browsers do. For example, they do not typically process Javascript or handle `<noscript>` normally. Because of this, there's no way for the page itself to know if it's a bot that retrieved it.

Comment: For testing I also added an Iframe tag with src pointing to my log link. This iframe gets executed all the time. But things inside noscript is not getting executed. if iframe gets executed then ideally noscript should also get executed.

Comment: GA relies on a specific image url being retrieved when JS is disabled. If that image isn't retrieved, GA can't do its tracking.

Comment: yes.. GA gives an img src. so the same thing I tried to do inside a noscript tag. noscript tag will it only display a text without fetching an img src.

Comment: Afaik, images aren't loaded in `<noscript>`. GA's docs say to add a specific `<iframe>` to the `<noscript>` element. See https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried all three elements. img, link and iframe in noscript tag.